# testexecute taking too much time to copy the log after the execution complete

Tags: unit-testing, automation, testcomplete

I executed the test and copied the result to another folder, but TestExecute taking too much time to copy log and images. Execution time of test is 4 hours and TestExecute taking approx 1 hours to copy the logs. What should i do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reducing the size of the log. To do this, disable Visualizer to get rid of tons of images. Make use of the **[Store last … events](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/69387/)** option to avoid posting boring event messages for successful test runs.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, One more thing I want to as, it reduces the size of .mht or .html log file but still when I export the log results it contains images. How do I ignore images while exporting.

Comment: If you are exporting results from a script, you can use the **ExportVisualizerImages** parameter of the [SaveResultsAs Method](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/75301/). When exporting from the Log panel in TestComplete, uncheck the **Save Visualizer images** box. When using TestExecute, just disable Visualizer on playback for your test project.